# How to Show rewarded Video in flutter when a user clicks a flat button

Tags: flutter, admob, flutter-dependencies, flutter-appbar, flutterwebviewplugin

I am new to Flutter and I need help in showing rewarded ads in my flutter app.
The app is used to load my website, my idea is to show rewarded videos when the user clicks a flat button and when the video is over or closed I need to get them to my website which is loaded in the background.
For showing the website I use web view plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initstate just load the rewarded ad,

```
// load the rewarded video ad
   RewardedVideoAd.instance
    .load(
    adUnitId: RewardedVideoAd.testAdUnitId,
    targetingInfo: targetingInfo);

// listen for the rewarded add events
RewardedVideoAd.instance.listener =
    (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {
  print("Rewarded Video Ad event $event");
  if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {
    // here, you can load your website using your webview plugin
  }
};
```

Inside your onPressed() method, just show Rewarded Video Ad by using,

```
onPressed: () {
                RewardedVideoAd.instance.show();
              },
```

You're done.

Answer (score 0):

To load the rewarded ad

```
    RewardedVideoAd.instance.listener =
        (RewardedVideoAdEvent event, {String rewardType, int rewardAmount}) {
      if (event == RewardedVideoAdEvent.rewarded) {
        setState(() {
          rewarded = true; 
        // here, you can perform your task  
        });
      }
    };
```

This is how listener works. You don't have to assign this listener to anywhere. All you need to do is call

```
RewardedVideoAd.instance.load(...)
```

On Press you can call like -

```
onPressed: () {
                RewardedVideoAd.instance.show();
              },
```